How to resolve "Found legacy AddReg operation using non-relative key" error during INF verification Windows 11 24H2 Build 26100?
Trying to pass the Windows HLK INF verification test on Windows 11 24H2 26100 Build.
I have been using the Windows kits tool InfVerif.exe to validate my inf file and execute
infverif.exe /u "absolute inf file path"
The INF AddReg directive section, entries have been created as follows:
HKLM, %SmartCardName%HKLM, %SmartCardName%,"ValueName1",0x00000001,"ValueData1"HKLM, %SmartCardName%,"ValueName2",0x00000001,"ValueData2"

Upon validation with the infverif.exe tool, an error code "1304" is reported: Found legacy AddReg operation using a non-relative key.
After changing the non-relative key to a relative key (HKR), infverif.exe successfully passes the validation of the INF file. However, the driver's automatic load fails, resulting in the particular registry entries not being created anymore.
The goal is to configure the INF file so that it passes validation and enables the driver to load automatically without issues when the HKLM is replaced with HKR.

What is SmartCardName in the Strings section?

It sounds like you've already identified the problem, and you maybe just don't want to admit to yourself what you need to do to fix it ;)
As you already identified, the test has failed because it saw that HKLM in your INF, and the only way to fix it is to use HKR instead. This, of course, changes where the registry value goes. So your driver code needs to be updated to look for the registry value in the new location.
Depending on which part of the INF is referencing the AddReg section, you can use either IoOpenDriverRegistryKey or IoOpenDeviceRegistryKey to have your driver open the key that the INF's HKR-based directive wrote.
Note that, depending on what exactly is getting written, you may need to consider how to safely migrate from an old INF into a new INF. For example, if the INF writes HKLM\SYSTEM\CCS\Services\MyDriver\Parameters!PollInterval, but the end-user can customize the PollInterval by writing to the Parameters key, then your driver needs to have a bit of logic to check if the old value exists, and to migrate it up into the new location. If you don't expect anyone to modify the registry data at runtime, then you don't need to worry about upgrading old state.
Also note that we are trying to separate data that comes from the INF from user-supplied data. This isn't currently rigidly enforced on most editions of Windows, but it may be enforced more strictly on future versions of the OS. So you should use this as an opportunity to separate out the INF's default values from user-provided override values. This is what DRIVER_REGKEY_TYPE is for: your driver might read a default value from the INF using DriverRegKeyParameters, but then allow the default to be overridden with a DriverRegKeySharedPersistentState key if an override exists there. (The only difference between SharedPersistent and just Persistent is that usermode is allowed to modify the Shared one. So if you have a usermode service that writes to the data, use Shared. Otherwise, if ONLY the driver ever touches the value, use the non-Shared version.)
If it helps, here's a bit of backstory. Originally, INFs were allowed to make any change to the system. But this leads to a few problems: it's difficult to be sure a driver package is cleanly uninstalled/updated/migrated if it can do literally anything. So we've defined a restricted subset of the INF directives that can be cleanly isolated from the system and from other INFs. This allows the OS to do more robust offline install of driver packages, fast updates, guaranteed cleanup upon uninstall, and (maybe someday) side-by-side driver versions.
For the registry and filesystem, this means that INFs can't hardcode any absolute paths — they should only write to their dedicated registry keys and disk path. The driver, likewise, should only read from these isolated paths.
